# Setting Hiberate Action to Power Button

Tags: gnome, 16.10, hibernate, systemd

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop on a Lenovo Ideapad Z510, with the Gnome 3.22 desktop environment.

While I *can* manage to get the power button to suspend by setting `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power, power-button-action = suspend`, setting the `power-button-action` to `hibernate` does not work.

In investigating the issue, it seems that there are three possible systems that may be responsible for the issue here (in no particular order):

- ACPI
- Systemd
- Gnome

I can confirm that the lid switch of my system is handled through systemd (setting `HandleLidSwitch` in `logind.conf`), but editing `HandlePowerKey` does not appear to do anything.

Can someone please suggest how to set the power button to hibernate on button press? Or how best to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks much

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of sleuthing, I found some additional details about how systemd's [logind works here](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) (more specifically, how logind uses policies through [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/)), which ultimately led me to the [solution to my issue here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html). **What fun!**